# Button to add table row with with input tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with different user inputs. I want the user to be able to add more rows.

```
<table>
    <tbody id="tbody_ID">
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text"></td>
            <td><input type="text"></td> 
            <td><input type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="add_row();"/>
```

This works.

```
function add_row()
{
    document.getElementById("tbody_ID").insertRow(1).innerHTML = "<td>test</td>";
}
```

But this does not.

```
function add_row()
{
    document.getElementById("tbody_ID").insertRow(1).innerHTML = "<td><input type="text"></td>";
}
```

I used a different function that clones the entire table row.

```
function add_row()
{
    var table_row = x.parentNode.parentNode.cloneNode(true);
    document.getElementById("tableID").appendChild(table_row);
}
```

But I don't want all of the columns to be the same as the original.

Comment: You need to escape the `"` like this `"<td><input type=\"text\"></td>"`